# How to set selections on an Angular multiselect with reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, multi-select

The best way to explain the issue... in this StackBlitz, I'd like to set the selection to 'Florida' and see that option selected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-dropdown-reactive-forms-jb7x2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I am able to set and get the values just fine from the FormControl, but visually the select does not show the options properly selected.

Answer (score 0):

Only you have to access the attribute you want to update, in this case the one on line 43 on app.component.html

```
{{ registrationForm?.getRawValue().cityName }}
```